# Drag and drop from PyQt 4.x to OSX file system

Tags: drag-and-drop, qt4, pyqt, osx-snow-leopard

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854546/how-to-implement-a-dragn-drop-from-a-qt-application-to-a-file-system-folder), I'd like to be able to drag and drop an image from a PyQt application to an OSX file system.

However, when I use the following code, nothing appears at the drop location.

It seems like I'm very close. If I change `mimeData.setData(mimeType, byteArray)` to `mimeData.setData("text/plain", selectedImagePath)`, I do get an "Untitled clipping" file at the drop destination, so at least I can be sure that the drag and drop action is working.

```
def startDrag(self, event):     

    selectedImagePath = "/sample/specified/file.jpg"


    ## convert to  a bytestream
    #
    mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
    image = QtGui.QImage(selectedImagePath)
    extension = os.path.splitext(selectedImagePath)[1].strip(".")
    mimeType = "image/jpeg" if extension in ["jpeg", "jpg"] else "image/png"

    byteArray = QtCore.QByteArray()
    bufferTime = QtCore.QBuffer(byteArray)
    bufferTime.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
    image.save(bufferTime, extension.upper())

    mimeData.setData(mimeType, selectedImagePath)

    drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
    drag.setMimeData(mimeData)

    result = drag.start(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)

    event.accept()
```

Where am I going wrong?

I realize I also need to set the name of the dropped media, so any guidance on that will be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify this process a bunch by not doing it with image mimetypes and setting the buffer. If you use urls, it will be a more universal approach...

An example for a custom QLabel:

```
class Label(QtGui.QLabel):

    ...

    def mousePressEvent(self, event): 

        event.accept()

        selectedImagePath = "/Users/justin/Downloads/smile.png"

        # a pixmap from the label, or could be a custom
        # one to represent the drag preview 
        pixmap = self.pixmap()

        # make sure the thumbnail isn't too big during the drag
        if pixmap.width() > 320 or pixmap.height() > 640:
                pixmap = pixmap.scaledToWidth(128)

        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimeData.setUrls([QtCore.QUrl(selectedImagePath)])

        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
        # center the hotspot image over the mouse click pos
        drag.setHotSpot(QtCore.QPoint(
            pixmap.width() / 2, 
            pixmap.height() / 2))

        dropAction = drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction, QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
```

Now the desktop will just interpret the url, and the naming is automatic. Enjoy!

Comment: I'll give this a try. You're a genius, jdi.