# Drag-and-drop onto the desktop or into a specific folder, without temporary storage.

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qt4

I've written a little file-transfer application written in C++ using Qt 4.x. It logs into a server, shows the user a list of files available on the server, and lets the user upload or download files.

This all works fine; you can even drag a file in from the desktop (or from an open folder), and when you drop the file icon into the server-files-list-view, the dropped file gets uploaded to the server.

Now I have a request for the opposite action as well. My users would like to be able to drag a file out of the server-files-list-view and onto the desktop, or into an open folder window, and have that file get downloaded into that location.

That seems like a reasonable request, but I don't know how to implement it. Is there a way for a Qt application to find out the directory corresponding to where "drop event" occurred, when the icon was dropped onto the desktop or into an open folder window? Ideally this would be a Qt-based platform-neutral mechanism, but if that doesn't exist, then platform-specific mechanisms for MacOS/X and Windows (XP or higher) would suffice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt 4.x: how to implement drag-and-drop onto the desktop or into a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724252/qt-4-x-how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-onto-the-desktop-or-into-a-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Even though I have never done exactly what you intend, I reckon this is doable with Qt.

You first have to deal with the drag event. This depends on the view you are using to see the files heirarchy in your server. Anyway here is a link to help you enable drag files from your view: http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/model-view-dnd.html In short it's just a couple a virtual functions to reimplement. The doc is here to help.

You may also see this link about how Drag/Drop events are handled in Qt: http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/dnd.html

I was about to answer about the drop event, when I noticed that the same question was asked word for word 3 years ago...
[Qt 4.x: how to implement drag-and-drop onto the desktop or into a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724252/qt-4-x-how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-onto-the-desktop-or-into-a-folder)

Comment: thanks for the reply. but how can we find the targeted path, where we have to download the File/s?